# How to use bearer token auth for POST request to ADO in Postman?

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-devops, postman

Here I'm trying post request send to ADO using Postman

I tried with Basic token in Postman to send post request, It worked with PAT like below:

[image]

I wanted to try without giving username and PAT in postman so, I generated bearer token by sending client ID & Secret to the below url
https://login.microsoft.com...//

I got bearer token as response, and pasted it in Bearer token box:

[image]

When I pasted that token in post man to send post request to ADO it is showing 401(unauthorized)
This is URL: [https://dev.azure.com/{pipeline_name}/{organization_name}/_release?_a=releases&view=mine&definitionId=x](https://dev.azure.com/%7Bpipeline_name%7D/%7Borganization_id%7D/_release?_a=releases&view=mine&definitionId=x)

Please guide me where am I doing wrong while sending the request.

Comment: Not very clear what the exact scenario is and how the token was generated. Add some more details for the context of this post.

Comment: I edited my question, please review it again

Comment: So error 401 is clear that you have to authorize to the service. You can not get results until the server won't know who you are.

Comment: Correct, It is working fine with Basic token, but I want use Bearer token instead

Answer (score 0):

I think the core issue is that ADO does not accept Bearer Token but need to pass it as OAuth 2.0 token. Change the Authorization to Oauth2.0 and on the right side pane under Available tokens, put the value that you generated for token and test.
Screenshot attached for reference.[image]

Comment: Thanks I will definitely try this.

Comment: @SaiVarunKumar - Did you get this working successfully with the above suggestion?